# What is the best solution for header + content to be 100% height without scrolling

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a three-column css layout with a header on top. On the left there will be the navigation, on the right a small column, with some advertisement maybe or so and in the middle there will be the content.
I would like DIVs left, right and middle go to the bottom of the page (so i guess i need height:100%) and i want the header have a fixed height of 60px.
I tried several solutions, which i found on the internet but if give everyone a height of 100% (so that the background of "right" and "left" to the bottom of the page) I always have to scroll a bit. I m pretty sure, that is because of the header having a absolute height value. Even though i put everything in a container which has the height of 100%.

My html looks like that:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header"><h1>Header</h1></div>
        <div id="left">
            <ul id = "nav">
                <li><a href="link.html">Link1</a></li>
                <li><a href="link.html">Link2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="right"><p>Advertisement 1 </p><p>Advertisment 2</p></div>
        <div id="middle">
            some content
        </div>
    </div>
```

and the corresponding CSS to it is:

```
html,body{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}

#container{
    position:relative;
    width: 850px; /*Width of main container*/
    margin: 0 auto; /*Center container on page*/
    height:100%;
}

#header{
    width: 850px;
    background: #EAEAEA;
    height: 90px; /*Height of top section*/
    text-align: center;
}

#left {
    width: 200px;
    float:left;
    background: #CCFFFF;
    height:100%


}
#middle{
    width: 490px;
    margin-left:200px;
    padding-left:10px;
    height:100%;

}

#right {
    width: 150px;
    float: right;
    background: #e0eeee;
    height:100%;

}

#left ul {
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;   
    width: 200px;

}
```

Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Change `position: relative;` to `position: absolute;` within your #container id. At this point you may have your left, middle, and right behind the header. If so you will add `top: 90px;` making sure that the value after top matches the height of your header div.